# lxml convert element to elementtree

Tags: python, element, lxml, elementtree

The following test code reads a file, and using `lxml.html` generates the leaf nodes of the DOM/Graph for the page.

However, I'm also trying to figure out how to get the input from a "string". Using:

```
lxml.html.fromstring(s)
```

doesn't work, as this generates an `Element` as opposed to an `ElementTree`.

So, I'm trying to figure out **how to convert an element to an ElementTree**.

#### [my test code]

```
import lxml.html
from lxml import etree    # trying this to see if needed 
                          # to convert from element to elementtree


  #cmd='cat osu_test.txt'
  cmd='cat o2.txt'
  proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  s=proc.communicate()[0].strip()

  # s contains HTML not XML text
  #doc = lxml.html.parse(s)
  doc = lxml.html.parse('osu_test.txt')
  doc1 = lxml.html.fromstring(s)

  for node in doc.iter():
  if len(node) == 0:
     print "aaa ",node.tag, doc.getpath(node)
     #print "aaa ",node.tag

  nt = etree.ElementTree(doc1)        <<<<< doesn't work.. so what will??
  for node in nt.iter():
  if len(node) == 0:
     print "aaa ",node.tag, doc.getpath(node)
     #print "aaa ",node.tag
```

---

#### UPDATE 1:

(parsing html instead of xml)
Added the changes suggested by Abbas. got the following errs:

```
    doc1 = etree.fromstring(s)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2532, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:48621)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1545, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72232)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1424, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71093)
  File "parser.pxi", line 938, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:67862)
  File "parser.pxi", line 539, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64244)
  File "parser.pxi", line 625, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:65165)
  File "parser.pxi", line 565, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64508)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'nbsp' not defined, line 48, column 220
```

#### UPDATE 2:

Managed to get the test working. I'm not exactly sure why. If someone with py chops wants to provide an explanation, that would help future people who stumble on this.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from lxml.html import parse

doc1 = parse(StringIO(s))

for node in doc1.iter():
    if len(node) == 0:
        print "aaa ", node.tag, doc1.getpath(node)
```

It appears that the StringIO module/class implements IO functionality which satisfies what the parse package needs to go ahead and process the input string for the test html. similar to what casting provides in other languages perhaps...

Comment: The xml parser is objecting to the '&nbsp;' in your HTML. Your HTML has to be well formed and either must not contain characters that the parser cannot digest or they should be escaped correctly.

Comment: hey Abbas.  I don't agree with what you're saying. The html in the test file now works, when I implement the solution I provided above, using the StringIO in the parse.

Comment: That's because you are now using an HTML parser (lxml.html) and StringIO. etree. etree tries to parse HTML but fails because of characters encoded for HTML (&nbsp;). I don't know why you would disagree with me when I proposed a solution based on your requirement of getting an ElementTree from etree by passing it an string. You later changed your solution, my solution is still valid for your original requirement.

Answer (score 11):

To get the root tree from an `_Element` (generated with `lxml.html.fromstring`), you can use the `getroottree` method:

```
doc = lxml.html.parse(s)
tree = doc.getroottree()
```

Answer (score 6):

The `etree.fromstring` method parses an XML string and returns a root element. The `etree.ElementTree` class is a tree wrapper around an element and as such requires an element for instantiation.

Therefore, passing the root element to the `etree.ElementTree()` constructor should give you what you want:

```
root = etree.fromstring(s)
nt = etree.ElementTree(root)
```

Comment: hey Abbas. thanks for the reply...   tried it, got the err listed above. (i'm parsing html, instead of xml)

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question as well.

Comment: This works for an XML string parsed from an Atom-like response

Answer (score 1):

An `_Element`, such that is returned by a call like:

```
tree = etree.HTML(result.read(), etree.HTMLParser())
```

Can be made an `_ElementTree` like so:

```
tree    = tree.getroottree() # convert _Element to _ElementTree
```

Hope that's what you expect.